# Different no. of columns on different screen resolutions

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap responsive to create a website.
In the middle of the page, there is a div that contains many boxes.

The requirement is that

1. On a big screen I should place 3 boxes per row, on a medium-big screen I should place 2 boxes per row, on a small screen I should place 1 box per row.
2. The box width (same width for all boxes) should always be maximized to fill up the full width of the div.

The trouble is I can meet each requirement but not both.

To meet only 1, I can specify fixed width for each box, and let them float left, but the boxes won't resize.

To meet only 2, I can use the bootstrap span class on the box (using row-fluid on the parent div), and the boxes will always be resized according to resolution, but no. of boxes per row is always the same.

How do I meet both 1 and 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add unique `class` or `id` to the box you want to disappear pls.. take a look with my [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/rKA2q/)

hope this help

**note:** *to see the effect scroll the fiddle to expand the screen width*

**Update**

html

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="box1"></div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
    <div class="box3"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
.wrapper {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
.wrapper div {
    float:left;
    width:22%;
    border:1px solid red;
    height:100px;
    margin:0 2% 0 0;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 368px){ 

    .wrapper div {
        width:45%;
        margin:10px 2% 0 0;
    }
}
```

working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhunlio/rKA2q/3/)

Comment: hi the box does not disappear, it should appear on the 2nd row, if displaying at two boxes per row.

Comment: thank you. you are amazing. an answer without resorting to js